# Disable button after knockoutjs extenders fail

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I am trying to make a custom validation using knockout js extenders. This extender is just supposed to check if the entered input is a number.

If I leave it blank I get the validation rule `Cannot be empty` and i cannot press the button. If i type a letter i get the validation rule `Must be a number` but the button is still enabled. 
The commented out code disables the button but also changes the css, and I don't think that is the best solution, since the `required` extender works fine.

Is there a way to prevent the submit button from submitting when the numeric extender fails?

```
ko.extenders.numeric = function (target, message) {
    target.hasError = ko.observable();
    target.validationMessage = ko.observable();

    function validate(value) {
        if (isNaN(value)) {
            target.hasError(true);
            target.validationMessage(message);

            console.log("This is NaN");

            //$('#btnSearch').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
            target.hasError(false);

            //$('#btnSearch').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    }

    target.subscribe(validate);

    return target;
}
```

Here is my observable:

```
this.accountNumber = ko.observable().extend({ required: { message: "Cannot be empty" }, numeric: "Must be a number" });
```

Comment: Use the `disable` binding on the button, and bind it to the `hasError` that your extender sets.
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/disable-binding.html

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`disable` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/disable-binding.html) on the button, and bind it to the `hasError` that your extender sets.